# Adding submenu's to explorer context menu

Tags: c#, contextmenu, submenu, explorer

I have a bit of code based of [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/174369/How-to-Write-Windows-Shell-Extension-with-NET-Lang), which allows me to add extra functionality for to the windows explorer context menu. I have been able to successfully get this working.

However I now want to add multiple items into the context menu, and add it inside a submenu. However I can't seem to work out, firstly how to add the submenu into it, then how to link the extra items to be inside that menu.

```
        // Use either InsertMenu or InsertMenuItem to add menu items.
        MENUITEMINFO mii = new MENUITEMINFO();
        mii.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(mii);
        mii.fMask = MIIM.MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM.MIIM_STRING | MIIM.MIIM_FTYPE | 
            MIIM.MIIM_ID | MIIM.MIIM_STATE;
        mii.wID = idCmdFirst + IDM_DISPLAY;
        mii.fType = MFT.MFT_STRING;
        mii.dwTypeData = this.menuText;
        mii.fState = MFS.MFS_ENABLED;
        mii.hbmpItem = this.menuBmp;
        if (!NativeMethods.InsertMenuItem(hMenu, iMenu, true, ref mii))
        {
            return Marshal.GetHRForLastWin32Error();
        }
```

That is the code I have to add the item currently. Unsure how i need to modify this for a submenu, as well as how to link the click action of the multiple items.

There is a shellExtLib which is what has most of that stuff defined, and looks like it is just importing stuff from the user32.dll. There is also a InvokeCommand() defined, which is where my actual "action-taking" code is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the solution I ended up with:

```
    private MENUITEMINFO CreateSubMenu(string menuText, IntPtr menuIcon, IntPtr hSubMenu, bool isEnabled = true)
    {
        MENUITEMINFO subMenu = new MENUITEMINFO();
        subMenu.cbSize = (uint)Marshal.SizeOf(subMenu);
        subMenu.fMask = MIIM.MIIM_BITMAP | MIIM.MIIM_SUBMENU | MIIM.MIIM_STRING | MIIM.MIIM_FTYPE | MIIM.MIIM_STATE;
        subMenu.hSubMenu = hSubMenu;
        //subMenu.wID = itemID;
        subMenu.fType = MFT.MFT_STRING;
        subMenu.dwTypeData = menuText;
        subMenu.fState = isEnabled ? MFS.MFS_ENABLED : MFS.MFS_DISABLED;
        subMenu.hbmpItem = menuIcon;
        //itemID++;
        return subMenu;
    }
```

Combined with:

```
    IntPtr hSubMenu = NativeMethods.CreatePopupMenu();

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    public static extern IntPtr CreatePopupMenu();
```